# How can I add the border in table

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have used drupal 7.38.

My question is I have created a view for product stock.

In this view I have used the table structure. When stock is empty then mail go to the stock manager.

In mail the product display in **p tag** but I want to show in **table** format show how can I do this?

I have some change on the views-view-table--stocks.tpl.php and views-view.tpl.php.

Comment: What is sending the email ? Rules ? Do you use Commerce Stock module ? Commerce Stock Notification ? If the email is sent by a rule, you can modify its template by editing this rule, see "Action" -> "Send email" for the rule.

Comment: I have created a custom rules component  for stock notification.when stock is empty then rules is send the mail to the stock manager. In  views I have selected table format but in mail table border not display, in rules component body I have written like this   `   <p>Hi Rahul,</p>
  <br />
  <p>Please check stocks level given below</p>
  <br />
  <p><?php print views_embed_view('stocks', 'block_1');?></p>` when I use here **table** then also table display without border.

Answer (score 0):

In your email body you could add a  element :

```
<style>
  .views-table-class { border: 1px solid black }
</style>
```

I guess you can add a CSS class ("views-table-class") to the table in Views interface. If not, using chrome dev tools / firebug you should be able to find a CSS selector to reach the table.

More info on CSS borders [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border). You can also add your CSS class on the table with your .tpl file like explained [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/how-to-add-css-class-to-a-table-created-using-views).

Hope it helps !